# Dictionary Comprehension within pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary-comprehension

Trying to match a dictionary item with a string value from another column.
sample data:

```
df =     A    B
     0  'a'  {'a': '2', 'b': '5'}
     1  'c'  {'a': '2', 'b': '16', 'c': '32'}
     2  'a'  {'a': '6', 'd': '23'} 
     3  'd'  {'b': '4', 'd': '76'}
```

I'm trying to get the following out:

```
Df =     A    B
     0   'a'  {'a': '2'}
     1   'c'  {'c': '32'}
     2   'a'  {'a': '6'}
     3   'd'  {'d': '76'}
```

I got this far not inside a dataframe:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k == 'a'}
```

for a single line, but I couldn't get this to work and to be fair, I didn't expect it to work directly, but was hoping i was close:

```
Test_df['B'] = {k: v for k, v in test_df['B'].items() if k == test_df['A']}
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What do I need to do to get this to work, or is there a better more efficient way?

Comment: From a more efficient standpoint, when using pandas, if you have to loop through rows or columns manually you're usually shooting yourself in the foot. Whilst it may work, it will be orders of magnitude slower on a large dataset, and is considered an anti-pattern

Comment: I did suspect this, I'm just not sure how to get that value from the second column. The csv I am working with is not massive, but large enough to be awkward, at 78,000 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
df['B'] = [{x: d[x]} for x, d in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

Output:

```
   A            B
0  a   {'a': '2'}
1  c  {'c': '32'}
2  a   {'a': '6'}
3  d  {'d': '76'}
```

Comment: I get an error with the 'd[x]' part saying "TypeError: string indicies must be integers?

Comment: @iFunction: That would mean that at least one value in column `B` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Indeed, in this case you would need to check that `d` is a valid dictionary using `isinstance(d, dict)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thank you, it came straight out of a csv file so that's very likely, I thin k i can work with that, one of the other columns I was working with was an array and that needed stripping and splitting to get it into a proper string, so I think I know what I have to do now, thank you all for your help.

Comment: @iFunction: [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) will safely convert a string representation of a dictionary to a dictionary as long as it consists "of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis."

Comment: To use it with pandas: `df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].applymap(ast.literal_eval)`.

Comment: This is kind of solved, @mozway's solution works for under 10000 lines, but I get ValueError: malformed node or string if I put the whole data set of those two columns through, I've tried forcing the dictionary column to a string using .astype(str), before applying literal_eval, but that is not workind, what can this error be referring to, there are no null values within this column that I can find?

Comment: `literal_eval` requires a valid syntax, there is zero flexibility if a quote or comma is missing, which is likely the case in some of your cells. You have to identify those and remove them, maybe using a wrapper with try except?

Comment: Ok thanks, I can work with that now then, your solution worked on 9000 of the rows, looks like I've got to do some cleaning

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply and efficiently within pandas itself using the following:

```
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x: {x[0]: x[1][x[0]]}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   a   {'a': '2'}
1   c   {'c': '32'}
2   a   {'a': '6'}
3   d   {'d': '76'}
```

Note that there is no error checking for if a key does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyDict():
    def __init__(self, d: dict) -> None:
        self.dict = d

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return {x: self.dict[x] for x in other}
    
df.B.map(MyDict) - df.A
```